# Regexp pattern - gsub ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to make a gsub that when I make an input like this:

'09/02 10:00 hs any string'

Will give me back something like:

'09/02 10:00'

So my gsub should take out all the strings that are non-numbers but I need ':' and '/' to stay

Help please.

Comment: What you describe would give `"09/0210:00"` as in vinodadhikary's answer, not `"09/02 10:00"` as you give.

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takes out all the strings that are non-numbers but I need ':' and '/' to stay

```
"09/02 10:00 hs any string".gsub(/[^0-9\/:]/, '')    
# "09/0210:00"
```

Comment: You don't need `to_s` at the end. Instead of `0-9`, you should use `\d`. Otherwise, if you have a string like `"0-9\/:"`, you can do `tr("0-9\/:", "")`.

Comment: @sawa, You're right don't need the `to_s` as `gsub` returns string, copy paste error :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = '09/02 10:00 hs any string'.gsub(/(?<=^\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}).*/, '')
```

the idea is to not capture the date time putting it in a lookbehind.

Comment: Nope, it didn't. All the strings stayed the same. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @AlejoAmiras: You must display the result, not you old variable! It works, I have tested it!

Comment: I'm doing that, but it doesn't work... 
My input and output are just the same.